# How to get string input in a windows console application C++?

Tags: c++, windows, powershell, command-line-interface

I am trying to make an ASCII art type console application in C++ using Windows.h. I am referring to tutorials by [OneLoneCoder](https://github.com/OneLoneCoder). I have figured out how to print out characters/strings on the console while using windows.h library.

```
wchar_t* screen = new wchar_t[sWidth * sHeight];
HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL);
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole);

while(true){
    //code logic
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacterW(hConsole, screen, sWidth * sHeight, { 0 ,0 }, &dwBytesWritten);
}
```

I want to read string input by the user like we can read with `std::cin >> input;` *How do I do so?*

I have read [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput), [ReadConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsole) and some more documentation and I think it is not directly possible like we do with `std::cin` or `scanf()` and I would have to read individual keystrokes. *Is there any other method to get string input while drawing graphics on the console?*

I want to do stuff in console only. Like they have done in vim editor. Like we can navigate through text and after pressing semicolon we can type at commands and it executed.

Comment: @WeatherVane It is in GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE mode so std functions are not working

Comment: I notice you are using C++ so I removed the C tag and deleted the comment. But `_getch()` does not come from `stdin` anyway.

Comment: @WeatherVane tried this it won't work. It is not even stopping/blocking the while loop for input

Comment: What about [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) function?

Comment: it works but it is kinda overcomplicated. Detecting Keypresses and parsing it to  a string and doing buffer clear stuff is a bit too overkill for a text viewer